# Why does Ryuk love apples?

Tags: death-note

It is often seen in Death Note that Ryuk loves apple. Why is that? Do all Shinigami *(Death Gods)* love apples, is it the only food for Death Gods or does *he* just love apples?

Also.. Is it to signify the apple as the forbidden fruit?

[image]

Comment: they are juice !!!!

Comment: @osdamv, did you mean that they are `juicy` instead of `juice`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Ryuuk said that apples in his world were dry and awful, but in human world they were "Juicy."

This is most likely the reason why he enjoys apples. There's also probably some hidden meaning to it.

Comment: Hidden meaning? Like the symbolization of apple as the forbidden fruit and a death god's fondness to it?

Comment: Yep, like that.

Comment: Actually, the creator of Death Note specifically said there is no hidden meaning, and that he simply liked the way the colour of a red apple contrasted with the dark colours of Ryuuk. @xjshiya [(source)](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Symbolism)

Answer (score 23):

From the [wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Apples)

> Apples are Ryuk's favorite food and probably the only thing he eats.
>   *He likes apples from the human world because they are "so juicy"*. Ryuk
>   stated that apples are an addiction for him, like alcohol or
>   cigarettes for humans. Ryuk exhibits symptoms of withdrawal if he goes
>   without eating apples for a while. These symptoms include contorting
>   his body into uncomfortable positions and desperation to the point
>   that he will take orders for one (i.e. looking for hidden cameras in
>   Light's room).

Answer (score 13):

As [Kai already mentioned](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3199/51): Ryuuk said that apples are dry and awful in his Shinigami Realm, and that the ones in the human world are juicy.

If I also remembered correctly, he let Misa have a bite of one of these apples from the Shinigami Realm and she mentioned that it tasted like sand.

To answer the second part of your question: It is Ryuuk who loves apples. Another Shinigami, called Sidoh, does love chocolate instead of apples.

Answer (score 3):

I think the writer chose apples because they have both mythical and religious values , like in Adam and Eve's story or Newton and gravity. Apples are native to the Mediterranean where civilization began, they have been cultivated for thousands of years and that's why they have such big attention.